# Error in view: The ObjectContext has been disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Error: *The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.*

I am getting this error in my when my view is rendered in my application.  I have looked through the various SO answers to similar questions and haven't been able to figure my issue out.
Here is my class:

```
public class categoryList
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> getCategories()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> myList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (ProductContext context = new ProductContext())
        {
            List<CategoryModel> list = 
                 (from c in context.Categories select c)
                .ToList<CategoryModel>();

            myList = list
              .GroupBy(c => c.category, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
              .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().category, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            return myList;
        }

    }
}
```

And then here is my view code that is calling that:

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, "Category", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category.category, newBestPlay.Models.ProductModel.getCategories(), new { @class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category)
                </div>
            </div>
```

Edit: To help someone figure out my issue, I am pasting the entire ProductModel class:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Item #")]
    public int itemNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Product")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String product { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public String description { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public bool active { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image Name")]
    public String imageName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PDF Name")]
    public String PDFName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public virtual int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual CategoryModel Category { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }

    public static SelectList getCategories()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> requestList = newBestPlay.Models.categoryList.getCategories();

        return new SelectList(requestList, "Key", "Value");
    }


}
```

And here is the CategoryModel:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String category { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public bool active { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear why you're getting a list of categories, grouping them (why are there duplicates?), and then creating a dictionary where the key and value will be the same thing.  Why not just return something like `context.Categories.Select(c => c.category).Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList()`?

Comment: What is your `model` and how is this retrieved and set?  I'm going to guess it was from EF and that `model.Category` is lazy loaded, hence your error.

Comment: The error is most likely caused by lazy loading of related entities, such as accessing the `ProductModel` property or the call to `getCategories()`.

Comment: Where is my use of camelCase wrong?

Comment: As asked earlier, I am using the Entity Framework.

Comment: Charles, I tried your line of code, but I still need to convert the list to a Dictionary<string, string> somehow.

Comment: @dmikester1 ah, ok - my mistake, I hadn't realised this was something required by the HTML helper.  This method isn't the cause of your issue, though.

Comment: Try commenting-out the dropdownlistfor and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

This exception will be thrown when your context is configured for using LazyLoading. If lazy Loading is enabled, EF will only retrieve the objects you specify in the select clause.

1. If the "CategoryModel" class contains nested objects and you are using Lazy loading, those objects will not be retrieved from the database.
2. Since you are enclosing the select inside a using block, after the controller is disposed, the connection and therefore the context are already disposed.
3. If you are referencing one of those inner-class objects inside the view, such as "Model.InnerClass.Property", you will get this exception.

If the previous statements are true, you can try the following:

```
public class categoryList
{
   public static Dictionary<string, string> getCategories()
   {
       Dictionary<string, string> myList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       using (ProductContext context = new ProductContext())
       {
           List<CategoryModel> list = 
                   (from c in context.Categories.Include("PropertyName") select c)
                   .ToList<CategoryModel>();

           myList = list
           .GroupBy(c => c.category, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
           .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().category, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
           return myList;
       }
    }
}
```

If the inner object contains additional objects you should specify that too to in the include, so EF retrieves that info before disposing the context:

```
.Include("InnerProperty.NestedProperty")
```

I hope it helps

-----EDIT 1-----------

Here's a code sample:

```
public class ProductModel
{
   public virtual CategoryModel Category { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryModel 
{
   public virtual UserAddress Address {get; set;}
}

public class UserAddress
{
   public string Street1 {get; set;}
}
```

Assuming the previous models, the Include will be as follows:

```
List<CategoryModel> list = (from c in context.Categories
                                             .Include("Category") 
                                             .Include("Category.Address") 
                            select c)
                           .ToList<CategoryModel>();
```

Comment: On the declaration of the list I get this error: "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'newBestPlay.DAL.CategoryModel' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'category'."

Comment: The name specified must match the name of the Property contained in the context. In your case will be "Category.InnerPropertyName". You can also try with lambdas. Include(p=>p.Category.InnerProperty).

Comment: "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'newBestPlay.DAL.CategoryModel' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Category'." and second: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: Added a sample model. Take a look to it.

Comment: Still getting the same "The EntityType 'newBestPlay.DAL.CategoryModel' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Category'."

Comment: Try using lamdas. ".Include(p=>p.TheInnerProperty)".

Comment: Still getting "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'newBestPlay.DAL.CategoryModel' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'category'."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78578/discussion-between-charles-and-dmikester1).